# unable to find resource 'http://***.inc' in any resource loader

Tags: java, configuration, velocity

This is a part of one of my Velocity Templates.

```
#if($!user.type==2)
    <div class="main-site-styles">
        #include('http://***/ca/88/4-9924.inc')
    </div>
#end
```

When I run it, the IDE console gives

```
[http-apr-80-exec-4] ERROR apache.velocity   (CommonsLogLogChute.java:96)     - ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'http://***/ca/88/4-9924.inc' in any resource loader.
```

The URL is OK when access it in a browser. I don't know what configuration I forget to write in my velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocity engine gets the template loading / parsing jobs done by using implementations of an abstract class [ResourceLoader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/engine/tags/1.7/src/java/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ResourceLoader.java?view=markup). The default implementation is to load the resources from filesystem.

I think you intend to provide a custom behavior to the [URLResourceLoader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/engine/tags/1.7/src/java/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/URLResourceLoader.java?revision=1040245&view=markup) as you want to load the templates from filesystem and remote locations as well. That said if you [reference the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/engine/tags/1.7/src/java/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/URLResourceLoader.java?revision=1040245&view=markup), you should be able to implement a custom ResourceLoader that behaves the way you want it to.

One option, glom most of the code from URLResourceLoader and change the way it determines the template content to load from the filesystem/remote locations.

I would dump all of the material that does the opening of streams to the templates as you will be determining the specific locations you want to load for content.

Hopefully that can provide enough assistance to move forward. I would recommend pulling this in a debugger as well and determine what is and is-not passed in to the related load methods.